# How can I automate the creation of instances of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So in python 3 I am having trouble creating multiple instances of a class automatically. I am trying to make monopoly and here is the code sample that is giving me problems.

```
def numplayer():
    numplayer = int(input('How many players would you like? (up to four)'))
    while numplayer > 4 or numplayer < 1:
        numplayer = int(input('How many players would you like? (up to 
        four)'))
    for i in range(numplayer):
        PlayerMoney.append(1500)
```

What I want to do is also add something that will create the number of players that numplayers equals to in the for i in range(numplayer) function. I have the player as a class but I don't want to manually create every single class for every player. If there is a solution to this, please do tell. Thanks!

EDIT: So I think this might be bad wording in the title but I'm trying to create multiple instances of a single class (the player). 
Here is the code for the player class:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, money, position):
        self.name = name
        self.money = money
        self.position = position

    def DiceRoll(self):
        x = random.randint(1, 6)
        y = random.randint(1, 6)
        sum = x + y
        return [sum, x, y]

    def getName(self):
        return sef.name

    def getMoney(self):
        return self.money

    def getPosition(self):
        return self.position
```

Comment: I think you're conflating classes with instances. You don't create a new class for every person. The class is a blueprint, or an outline for the instance which is the actual player. Can we see your `player` class definition?

Comment: Deleted my answer because I realized that mypetition is right, you're conflating classes and instances of classes.

Comment: I don't think I mixed up classes and instances, but rather had bad wording in the title. I am trying to create instances of a single class automatically. I am not trying to create a class for every player.

Comment: There is one class but you need to create an **instance for every player**; what @mypetlion said.

Comment: What is `PlayerMoney`, is it a different class again to `Player`? If yes, please also include its definition; if no, please fix your question. If you were to instantiate a list of `Player` then you could refer to  `player[i].money`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create Class 
class Player:
    def greating(self):
        print 'Hello!'

# List to store instanses
l = []

for i in range(4):
   l.append(Player())

# Call Instance #1 methods
l[0].greating()
```

Here we have a player class and 4 instances from this class stored in l list.

Comment: In what way did this answer the question? And what is `test`? You didn't even define a constructor for your `Player` class.

Comment: @mypetion basically it creates the instances for him as he needs. btw, __init__ isn't mandatory to define the class in python

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you structure your code as below. It's usually a good idea for your function to `return` something.

```
def setup():

    n = int(input('How many players would you like? (up to 4)'))

    names = [input('Give name #{0}'.format(i)) for i in range(1, n+1)]

    return [Player(name, 1500, 0) for name in names]

players = setup()
```

Comment: yeah I know, but in the case of lists I don't need to return them because they are global (I defined the lists early on in my code)

Comment: Your code *may work* but `global` isn't always the best way to go. But you probably know that already.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just doing it for this because it isn't a huge project

Comment: ( Better than passing around a global list of `Player` is to create another class `Game` with a member `player[1:numplayer]` )

Comment: @JerryZhou you still shouldn't use global variables.